# Can't access session into admin phtml file on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, session, helper

I tried to set a session from a model file and access this on a phtml file like this and it's not working:

**`namespace/vendor/Model/ProcessModel.php`:**

```
    protected $backendSession;

    public function __construct(
        .....
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session $backendSession,
        ....
    ) {

        $this->backendSession = $backendSession;
       ...
    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

        $postdata = $this->_request->getPost();

        $t1 = $this->backendSession->setMyNam('test');
        $t2 = $this->backendSession->setMyNum('test2');
        $t3 = $this->backendSession->getMyNam();

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info(print_r($t3, true));
    }

}
```

When I logged this, I received my value in my `test.log` which means that the session is set.

Now I want to get this session in a phtml file located at `\namespace\vendror\view\adminhtml\templates\items\column\name.phtml`.

To do that in my helper file located at `\namespace\vendror\Helper\Product\View\Personalized.php` I have this:

```
protected $backendSession;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Session $backendSession,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->backendSession = $backendSession;
    ...
}

public function getSession(){

    return $this->backendSession;
}

public function getSession1(){

    return $this->backendSession->getMyNam();
}
```

and in my phtml file `name.phtml` I try to get this value like this:

```
$var=$this->helper('namespace\vendor\Helper\Product\View\Personalized');

$nam = $var->getSession()->getMyNam(); 
$num = $var->getSession1();
```

and I receive nothing.

If I set my function `getSession()` to return a value like: `return "text";` I receive this value in my phtml, but this is not working only with the session value.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I see in my phtml the value set in the session?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use sessions in templates.
You should create wrappers in the block class that the templates can use in order to set/get values.

Using the example above, create the methods in the block

```
public function setSessionData($key, $value)
{
    return $this->backendSession->setData($key, $value);
}

public function getSessionData($key, $remove = false)
{
    return $this->backendSession->getData($key, $remove);
}
```

Then use these functions to set or get the session in phtml file.